# Синхронизация доступа к списку

Tags: c#, коллекции, синхронизация

Есть список обработчиков события:

```
private list<handler> _handlers;

    public event eventhandler RainStart
    {
       add{
            lock(_handlers)
              _handlers.add(value)
          }
    remove{ handlers.remove(value)}
    }
```

Есть метод, рассылающий обновления:

```
public void SendUpdates()
{
lock(_handlers)
   {
    foreach(var handl in _handlers)
      {
        handl(this,EventArgs.empty);
      }
   }
}
```

Метод SendUpdates очень активно вызывается и при подписке из другого потока на событие RainStart приложение падает с ошибкой: "коллекция была изменена, невозможно выполнить операцию перечисления". Почему так происходит, ведь я же синхронизирую доступ к списку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему, какой-то из обработчиков отписывает себя (или другой обработчик, что маловероятно) из списка.

Дело в том, что блокировка через `lock` действует лишь на другие потоки, но не на ваш поток. А вызов обработчиков происходит в том же потоке, в котором выполняется метод `SendUpdates`.

Заметьте, что если бы блокировка случайно действовала в том же потоке, то вы получили бы просто зависание: ведь вызов обработчиков синхронный, а значит, код `handl(this,EventArgs.empty);` будет ждать, пока обработчик не завершится.

Вы можете, например, сделать так:

```
public void SendUpdates()
{
    List<handler> copy;

    lock(_handlers)
        copy = _handlers.ToList(); // это сделает копию списка

    foreach (var handl in copy)
        handl(this, EventArgs.empty);
}
```

При этом обработчик, отписавшийся от события, не изменит список-копию, который пробегается в цикле.

Заметьте, что вызов чужого кода (например, обработчика события) под блокировкой — почти всегда плохая идея, это прямой путь к зависанию.

Советую прочитать вот эту статью: [Eric Lippert, *Events and Races*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/29/events-and-races/). В ней описывается ещё пара проблем с многопоточными событиями, в дополнение к вашей.

---

Кстати, а зачем вам явный список обработчиков? Если вы полльзуетесь современной версией языка, вы можете упростить код и избавиться от головной боли:

```
public event EventHandler RainStart;

public void SendUpdates()
{
    RainStart?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Такой вызов является потокобезопасным, потому что подписка и отписка от стандартного события выполняются атомарно.

Comment: VladD, огромное спасибо за ответ! Список обработчиков требуется по другим причинам, так конечно я бы пользовался базовым EventHandler. "Дело в том, что блокировка через lock действует лишь на другие потоки, но не на ваш поток. " - Не могли бы Вы пояснить? Я думаю, что не только мне будет полезно, заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Sleeeper: Смотрите. Если вы в одном потоке делаете `lock`, и в другом в это же время пытаетесь сделать тоже `lock`, то второй поток будет ждать, пока первый не отпустит `lock`. Но в вашем случае это не так: второй `lock` вызывается в том же потоке, **внутри** обработчика! И в этом случае второй `lock` не блокируется, а немедленно выполняется.

Comment: Вы, как и всегда, очень доходчивы. Огромное спасибо за ответ и затраченное время.

Comment: @Sleeeper: Пожалуйста!